# 10 calculated field for each row

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write a query that shows all the accountnumbers and then I need to show the next 10 closing balances from the next 10 days from a specific startdate.

I have a dimension with accounts, a dimension with dates and a fact balance table that stores the opening and closing balance for each of the accounts.

The output needs to look like this:

BANK_NAME |  ACCOUNT_NR |  CB DATE1 |  CB DATE1 +1 |  CB DATE1 +2 .... | untill 10

I've tried to write a query like this:

```
    select information.bankname,information.branchname,information.holdername,information.accountnumber, information.CURRENCY, CB1.amount1, CB2.amount2, CB3.amount3, CB4.amount4, CB5.amount5, CB6.amount6, CB7.amount7,  CB8.amount8, CB9.amount9, CB10.amount10
from 
--eerste gegevens selecteren
(select a.BANK_NAME bankname, a.BRANCH_NAME branchname, a.HOLDER_NAME holdername, a.ACCOUNT_NUMBER accountnumber, a.CURRENCY currency
--relaties worden gelegd
from DIM_ACCOUNT a, FACT_AS_BALANCE b, DIM_DATE d 
where
b.balance_date_id = d.ID and
b.account_id = a.ID and
) information,

(select FACT_AS_BALANCE.CB_AMOUNT amount1
--relaties worden gelegd
from DIM_ACCOUNT a, FACT_AS_BALANCE b, DIM_DATE d 
where
b.balance_date_id = d.ID and
b.account_id = a.ID and
(d.CAL_DATE = TO_DATE ('20130101', 'YYYYMMDD'))) CB1,

(select FACT_AS_BALANCE.CB_AMOUNT amount2
--relaties worden gelegd
from DIM_ACCOUNT a, FACT_AS_BALANCE b, DIM_DATE d 
where
b.balance_date_id = d.ID and
b.account_id = a.ID and
(d.CAL_DATE = TO_DATE ('20130101', 'YYYYMMDD') + 1)) CB2,

(select FACT_AS_BALANCE.CB_AMOUNT amount3
--relaties worden gelegd
from DIM_ACCOUNT a, FACT_AS_BALANCE b, DIM_DATE d 
where
b.balance_date_id = d.ID and
b.account_id = a.ID and
(d.CAL_DATE = TO_DATE ('20130101', 'YYYYMMDD') + 2)) CB3,

(select FACT_AS_BALANCE.CB_AMOUNT amount4
--relaties worden gelegd
from DIM_ACCOUNT a, FACT_AS_BALANCE b, DIM_DATE d 
where
b.balance_date_id = d.ID and
b.account_id = a.ID and
(d.CAL_DATE = TO_DATE ('20130101', 'YYYYMMDD') + 3)) CB4,

(select FACT_AS_BALANCE.CB_AMOUNT amount5
--relaties worden gelegd
from DIM_ACCOUNT a, FACT_AS_BALANCE b, DIM_DATE d 
where
b.balance_date_id = d.ID and
b.account_id = a.ID and
(d.CAL_DATE = TO_DATE ('20130101', 'YYYYMMDD') + 4)) CB5,

(select FACT_AS_BALANCE.CB_AMOUNT amount6
--relaties worden gelegd
from DIM_ACCOUNT a, FACT_AS_BALANCE b, DIM_DATE d 
where
b.balance_date_id = d.ID and
b.account_id = a.ID and
(d.CAL_DATE = TO_DATE ('20130101', 'YYYYMMDD') + 5)) CB6,

(select FACT_AS_BALANCE.CB_AMOUNT amount7
--relaties worden gelegd
from DIM_ACCOUNT a, FACT_AS_BALANCE b, DIM_DATE d 
where
b.balance_date_id = d.ID and
b.account_id = a.ID and
(d.CAL_DATE = TO_DATE ('20130101', 'YYYYMMDD') + 6)) CB7,

(select FACT_AS_BALANCE.CB_AMOUNT amount8
--relaties worden gelegd
from DIM_ACCOUNT a, FACT_AS_BALANCE b, DIM_DATE d 
where
b.balance_date_id = d.ID and
b.account_id = a.ID and
(d.CAL_DATE = TO_DATE ('20130101', 'YYYYMMDD') + 7)) CB8,

(select FACT_AS_BALANCE.CB_AMOUNT amount9
--relaties worden gelegd
from DIM_ACCOUNT a, FACT_AS_BALANCE b, DIM_DATE d 
where
b.balance_date_id = d.ID and
b.account_id = a.ID and
(d.CAL_DATE = TO_DATE ('20130101', 'YYYYMMDD') + 8)) CB9,

(select FACT_AS_BALANCE.CB_AMOUNT amount10
--relaties worden gelegd
from DIM_ACCOUNT a, FACT_AS_BALANCE b, DIM_DATE d 
where
b.balance_date_id = d.ID and
b.account_id = a.ID and
(d.CAL_DATE = TO_DATE ('20130101', 'YYYYMMDD') + 9)) CB10;
```

I don't know if this is the correct way of doing this. But I really don't see any other way.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Oracle 11+, you can use the `PIVOT` clause, something along these lines:

```
WITH Date_Range as (SELECT id, cal_Date
                    FROM dim_Date
                    WHERE cal_Date >= TO_DATE('20130101', 'yyyymmdd')
                          AND cal_Date < TO_DATE('20130101', 'yyyymmdd') + 10)
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT Account.bank_name, Account.branch_name, 
             Account.holder_name, Account.account_number,
             Account.currency, Balance.cb_amount, Date_Range.cal_Date
      FROM dim_Account Account
      JOIN fact_as_Balance Balance
        ON Balance.account_id = Account.id
      JOIN Date_Range
           ON Date_Range.id = Balance.balance_date_id) Information
PIVOT(MAX(cb_amount)) FOR cal_Date IN (SELECT cal_Date FROM Date_Range)
```

Untested, as there's no sample data to go off of.  This should dynamically generate columns for all dates.
(Note that I'm against the use of `SELECT *`, but I'm unsure if not specifying the pivoted columns will still include them - it's not like we could necessarily guess the column names...)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT 
    a.bank_name bankname, 
    a.branch_name branchname, 
    a.holder_name holdername, 
    a.account_number accountnumber, 
    a.currency currency,
    SUM(CASE WHEN d.cal_date = to_date ('20130101', 'yyyymmdd')
             THEN fact_as_balance.cb_amount 
             ELSE 0 end) amount1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN d.cal_date = to_date ('20130101', 'yyyymmdd') + 1
             THEN fact_as_balance.cb_amount 
             ELSE 0 end) amount2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN d.cal_date = to_date ('20130101', 'yyyymmdd') + 1
             THEN fact_as_balance.cb_amount 
             ELSE 0 end) amount3,
    (continue for columns 4-10)
FROM 
    dim_account a
    JOIN fact_as_balance b ON a.id = b.account_id
    JOIN dim_date d ON b.balance_date_id = d.id 
GROUP BY    
    a.bank_name bankname, 
    a.branch_name branchname, 
    a.holder_name holdername, 
    a.account_number accountnumber, 
    a.currency currency
```

Comment: Hmm... You could at least cut down the number of columns in the `GROUP BY` by doing the `SUM(CASE...` in a subquery (the conditions don't reference `dim_account` at all); that would be likelier to use indices.  And `amount3` is supposed to be `+ 2`.